# How do you get the date from a dashed string to then use with laravels created_at?

Tags: php, string, date, laravel-5.3

So consider the following: `2017-04-09-some-text-here.md`

the easiest way I can think of doing this is to split: `explode("-", $string);`

and then use the `$result[0]`, `$result[1]`, `$result[2]` to then some how create an appropriate Created At time stamp with Laravel (How I create that time stamp I have no idea)

So this is where I turn to stack, **How do I properly and cleanly get the date from a piece of text as shown above, and then use it with laravel's `created_at` to set the `created_at` time stamp to `2017/04/09`**

Comment: are you need  `UnixTimeStamp`?
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php`

Comment: That doesn't help me extract the date from the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$re = '/2\d{3}([- \/])\d{2}([- \/])\d{2}/';
$str = 'TQ2 TR23RT2017-05-12 TR342T43T QT3 T34T34T2017/05/12 3tr3q2 tr R32T ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$dates = [];
if(isset($matches)){
    foreach($matches as $match){

        $dates[] = str_replace('-','/',$match[0]);
    }
}
print_r($dates);
```